# Reading Messages From Topic on storage blob through subscriber on Service Bus Explorer - C#

Tags: azure, azure-blob-storage, servicebus, azure-servicebus-topics

Working Scenario:

1. Post Msg1 to topic
2. Post Msg2 to topic
3. Read Msg1, Msg2

Not Working:

1. Post Msg1 to topic
2. Read Msg1 from topic through subscriber, but I'm not marking as complete.(Still on Queue)
3. Post Msg2 to topic
4. Read Msgs.. Actual: I read only Msg2 Expectation: Want to read Msg1, Msg2.

   ```
      if (namespaceManager.TopicExists(topic))
                   {
                       var lstOfValues = new List<SITConfirmation>();
                       SubscriptionClient Client = SubscriptionClient.CreateFromConnectionString(ConfigurationManager.ConectionString(), topic, subscriber);
                       IEnumerable<BrokeredMessage> messages = await Client.ReceiveBatchAsync(10, TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(500));
                    }
   ```

Comment: What's MaxDelliveryCount set on subscription? And how  is Storage Blob related to this?

Comment: MaxDelliveryCount is 10

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With `ReceiveBatchAsync(messageCount)` you're not promised to get the exact number of messages requested. Gateway could have all the messages or not. It will return whatever it has (gateway might have less/more/same number of messages that are actually stored on the broker entity).

From the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.servicebus.messaging.subscriptionclient?redirectedfrom=MSDN#Microsoft_ServiceBus_Messaging_SubscriptionClient_ReceiveBatchAsync_System_Int32_):

> As this is an approximation, fewer or more messages than messageCount may be returned.